# Trying to programatically set Secure Canvas URL, and Tab Secure Canvas URL:

Tags: facebook

I have an app which creates third party apps on the fly, now that facebook has made it compulsory for secure urls , I need to programmatic ally add secure urls to these app settings

Secure Canvas URL:
Secure page Tab Url

The documentation doesn't mention the variables for these hence its impossible to set these variables

I can set both these variables callback_url(for Canvas URL) and profile_tab_url(page Tab Url)

but the secure equivalent of these does not seem to be available to set, does it means we cannot set these values for third party apps created on the fly, apart from manually entering them in the app settings

see here, or am i missing something.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at this point there is no method for setting the new secure URL's via API.  There's a bug filed at: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16736

You can register and up vote to help get it resolved more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Also see:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15911